# objects not adding to another objects arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 2 objects. `WeatherStation` and `WeatherReading`.

I have an arraylist of `WeatherReading` objects in `WeatherStation` that I am trying to add to:

**WeatherStation Class:**

```java
public ArrayList<WeatherReading> readings = new ArrayList<WeatherReading>();

public WeatherStation(int id, double lat, double lon, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon;
        this.name = name;
}
```

I add to the `readings` arraylist by using `addReading()` which is inside the `WeatherStation` class.

```java
public boolean addReading(WeatherReading reading) {
        this.readings.add(reading);
        return true;
}
```

In another class named `Generator` I attempt to add these readings to this arraylist.

```java
public static void addReadings(ArrayList<WeatherStation> stations, String[] weatherData) {
        for(int i = 1; i < weatherData.length; i++) {
            WeatherReading currentReading = genReading(weatherData[i]);
            WeatherStation currentStation = genStation(weatherData[i]);
            if(currentReading.getId() == currentStation.getId()) {
                currentStation.addReading(currentReading);
            }
        }
    }
```

Although after this is completed I try and print out my `WeatherStations` and no readings have been added to the arraylist:

```java
WeatherStation [id=3226, lat=54.57, lon=-2.42, name=WARCOP (3226), readings=[]]
WeatherStation [id=3482, lat=52.651, lon=0.569, name=MARHAM (3482), readings=[]]
WeatherStation [id=3227, lat=54.68, lon=-2.45, name=GREAT DUN FELL (3227), readings=[]]
WeatherStation [id=3740, lat=51.5031, lon=-1.9924, name=LYNEHAM (3740), readings=[]]
WeatherStation [id=3230, lat=55.28, lon=-2.28, name=REDESDALE CAMP (3230), readings=[]]
WeatherStation [id=3743, lat=51.201, lon=-1.805, name=LARKHILL (3743), readings=[]]
WeatherStation [id=3488, lat=52.949, lon=1.127, name=WEYBOURNE (3488), readings=[]]
```

How can I make sure that I add to the `WeatherReading` objects arraylist and not have the arraylist be empty

Comment: You never add the weather data to any of the given stations, you just create a new one and add it to that station?

Comment: @R4yY  Yes I do? I do it in the `addReadings` method `currentStation.addReading(currentReading);`

Comment: Yes but thats currentStation, at no point it is set to one of the station coming from the stations ArrayList

Comment: In your `addReadings` method you are passing a List of stations.  But nowhere in that method do you use it.

Comment: What is the purpose of `stations` in your `addReadings` method?